# Leer excel con Imagen desde VB

Tags: excel, vb

Buenas a tod@s estoy leyendo un excel desde VB 2008, le correctamente cuando son datos primitivos, pero ahora necesito obtener la imagen que esta en el excel y mostrarla en la grilla y guardarla fisicamente como archivo, alguna idea de como conseguir eso? No he encontrado mucha informacion al respecto, este mi codigo con el cual puedo leer el Excel:

```
 Dim oDataAdapter_Excel As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
     Dim oConnection_Excel As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

     If ExcelFormCheck() Then
        oConnection_Excel = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection( _
              "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
              "Data Source=" & txtRuta.Text.Trim & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; IMEX=2"";")

        oDataAdapter_Excel = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter( _
             "select * from [" & txtHoja.Text & "$]  ", oConnection_Excel)

        moDataSetExcel = New System.Data.DataSet
        oDataAdapter_Excel.Fill(moDataSetExcel)
        oConnection_Excel.Close()

        Return True
     End If
```

este es el excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]